# Keep getting error messages when compiling newest version of admob on IOS6 SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, ios6

I've downloaded the newest version of googles admob sdk. But now I keep getting the following error when compiling in xcode 4.5 with the latest sdk.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADIdentifierUtilities.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You probably didn't add AdSupport.framework. Also remember to remove `-all_load` linker flag.

Comment: where do we find all_load flag

Comment: The "-all_load" can be found under "build settings" on your project or target. Open the settings and search for "other linking flags". If it is set you will find it there (note that this is not a default flag, so it may not be there)

Comment: Add the AdSupport.framework in your target 'Link Binary With Libraries'

Comment: Hint: The AdSupport.framework is a system framework provided by Apple, add it to Target > Build Phases > Link ...

Comment: Note: I had to add StoreKit.framework as well (may be because I'm using the DoubleClick addon headers?).

Comment: I was also facing exact problem, and got it solved by adding the suggested framework. Thanks.:)

Comment: I had this issue when removing a cordova plugin that used `AdSupport.framework` but another plugin still needed it. Worked for me :)

Comment: I have added AdSupport.framework and have removed `-all_load` flag. but still I am getting this error for Fyber SDK.

Answer (score 9):

AdSupport.framework need in xcode 4.5 and admob 6.x

Answer (score 1):

On the other way you can fix it without adding extra framework, remove the "-Obj" flag from "Linking > Other Linker Flags" **if this flag is not required for your project**.

I my case it was different, I had supported the GoogleConvertionTracking.lib but after couple of release customer decided to remove the GoogleConvertionTracking.lib from client. After removing all required code from client I started getting this error of  **""_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:"**

After going thru the support doc of GoogleConvertionTracking I found that I had added "-Obj" compiler flag under Under Linking > Other Linker Flags.

*** by removing this "-Obj" flag from "Linking > Other Linker Flags" for both rel/deb this error is gone.

**I don't have to add AddSupport.framework to get rid of this error**.
This change may be helpful for those who don't want to add extra framework to avoid the compilation error.