# Errors while adding Admob

Tags: ios, admob, linker-errors

I am trying to add Admob into my app. All I do is drop the Admob files into my app and I get these errors:

[image]

I had no errors before I add Admob...

Here is the full error:

```
error: unable to open executable '/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app/AppName'
```

Comment: Have you Set the `-ObjC` compiler flag? And linked all needed libraries?

Comment: what's the detail linker error info? may be you can try to use cocoapods (cocoapods.org) to manager your third-party libraries.

Comment: that's not the interesting part. it should be something like in this question and find it in Xcode's `output`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628249/keep-getting-error-messages-when-compiling-newest-version-of-admob-on-ios6-sdk

Comment: @lootsch But I am not getting any other errors...

Comment: thats unlikely. There should be an error thrown by the linker. Before the linker `failed with exit code`

Answer (score 0):

Link all Libraries from this list (step 3):

- AdSupport
- AudioToolbox
- AVFoundation
- CoreGraphics
- CoreTelephony
- MessageUI
- StoreKit
- SystemConfiguration

and add `-ObjC` to other linker flags for you `target` (step 4):
[image]

Source: [this guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#ios)