# [GADSlot state]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, admob

I have integrated AdMob into My Application. Now when i am pushing to the AdMob view it constantly gets crashed.

Here is the Crash log :

```
2014-04-03 17:56:40.134 myApp[2934:a0b] -[GADSlot state]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1133f700
2014-04-03 17:56:44.047 myApp[2934:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GADSlot state]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1133f700'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x050955e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x028998b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x05132903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0508590b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x050854ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   myApp                           0x0004a2ce -[GADSlot isMakingRequest] + 36
    6   myApp                           0x00049f2d -[GADSlot setAdType:andReloadRequest:] + 334
    7   myApp                           0x00048d0e -[GADBannerView setAdSize:andReload:] + 512
    8   myApp                           0x00049302 -[GADBannerView setAdSize:] + 62
    9   myApp                           0x0004957c -[GADBannerView initWithFrame:] + 172
    10  myApp                           0x00008822 -[JustStartVC viewDidLoad] + 18242
    11  UIKit                               0x015129a8 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
    12  UIKit                               0x01512c44 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    13  UIKit                               0x0152ca72 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 778
    14  UIKit                               0x01539757 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688
    15  UIKit                               0x0153a349 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    16  UIKit                               0x0167339d -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
    17  UIKit                               0x01469dd7 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    18  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x028ab81f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    19  QuartzCore                          0x012d972a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    20  QuartzCore                          0x012cd514 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    21  QuartzCore                          0x012cd380 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    22  QuartzCore                          0x01235156 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    23  QuartzCore                          0x012364e1 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    24  QuartzCore                          0x01236bb4 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0505d53e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x0505d48f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x0503b3b4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x0503ab33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x0503a94b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x02a999d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x02a997fe GSEventRun + 104
    32  UIKit                               0x013ff94b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    33  myApp                           0x00016b2d main + 141
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x056b9725 start + 0
    35  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to project settings > Build Settings And set `-ObjC` to Other Linker Flags.

[image]

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22585112/2115477

Answer (score 1):

I referred few discussions & found that there is an flag need to be added in build settings.

Here it is :

- Targets -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags
- I set here -ObjC

So now its working.