# [GADSlot state]: unrecognized selector sent to instance in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I am new to iOS development.

I am trying to implementing admob ads in iOS in my phonegap app so I googled & found somve[admob without plugin](http://therockncoder.blogspot.in/2012/05/cordova-phonegap-and-admob-together-ios.html).

after following all procedure,
I got an error **MyApp[2388:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GADSlot state]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10415920'**

so I google about & found that I have to change other Linker flags. **(-ObjC)**[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635283/admob-crashes-with-gadobjectprivate-changestate-unrecognized-selector)

**I have tried it but it is not working.**

**I am getting this error.**

this solution also not working for me. [[GADSlot state]: unrecognized selector sent to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837815/gadslot-state-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

```
2014-04-21 13:04:41.252 MyApp[2388:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GADSlot state]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10415920'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x038a85e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02acb8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x03945903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x0389890b ___forwarding___ + 1019
 4   CoreFoundation                      0x038984ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
 5   MyApp                            0x0001a01e -[GADSlot isMakingRequest] + 36
 6   MyApp                            0x00019c7d -[GADSlot setAdType:andReloadRequest:] + 334
 7   MyApp                            0x00018a5e -[GADBannerView setAdSize:andReload:] + 512
 8   MyApp                            0x00019052 -[GADBannerView setAdSize:] + 62
 9   MyApp                            0x00019381 -[GADBannerView initWithAdSize:] + 171
 10  MyApp                            0x00003e17 -[MainViewController viewDidLoad] + 118
 11  UIKit                               0x0021c318 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
 12  UIKit                               0x0021c5b4 -[UIViewController view] + 35
 13  MyApp                            0x00002997 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 763
 14  UIKit                               0x00102355 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 309
 15  UIKit                               0x00102b95 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1536
 16  UIKit                               0x001073a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
 17  UIKit                               0x0011b87c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
 18  UIKit                               0x0011bde9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
 19  UIKit                               0x00109025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
 20  GraphicsServices                    0x038062f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
 21  GraphicsServices                    0x03805e01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
 22  CoreFoundation                      0x03823d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
 23  CoreFoundation                      0x03823a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
 24  CoreFoundation                      0x0384e77c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
 25  CoreFoundation                      0x0384dac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
 26  CoreFoundation                      0x0384d8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
 27  UIKit                               0x00106add -[UIApplication _run] + 840
 28  UIKit                               0x00108d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
 29  MyApp                            0x000025fd main + 95
 30  MyApp                            0x00002595 start + 53
 )
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

please help me out.

**main.m**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");//It highlight this line when exception accoure.
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    CGFloat screenXPos = (screenWidth/2);
    CGFloat screenYPos = screenHeight - kGADAdSizeBanner.size.height;
    [bannerView_ setCenter:CGPointMake(screenXPos, screenYPos)];
    bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testing = NO;
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:request];

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[GADSlot state\]: unrecognized selector sent to instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837815/gadslot-state-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Comment: @Visput :- As i have added this in question that it is not working for me.

Comment: Your MainViewController set up GADBannerView incorrectly.  So it is using a GADSlot object where some other object class should be used (one that recognizes the selector "state").  If you have the source for GADBannerView, examine it and see where the object reference is coming from.

Comment: As I said i am totally new to ios devlopment but if you can help me i can post code of `GADBannerView`

Comment: Please post some code and I will see what I can do.

Comment: @voyage11 :~ I have added code as well.

Comment: just for me to be sure have you tired to set Other Linker Flags -ObjC for both Release and Debug as well as -force_load flag instead -ObjC ?

Comment: I have only **-ObjC** in linker flag in for all release,debug & distribution. & i havent use -force_load flag.

Comment: How many targets do you have? Are you sure you changed the settings for the correct one?

Comment: yes. I am sure . i have checked it twice. before put in bounty.

Comment: Where is bannerView_ declared?  Did you by chance mean _bannerView?

Comment: @JonBrooks I have declared in `MainViewController.h` file with variable name `bannerView_`

Answer (score 2):

I think, GADBannerView is not set up correctly. If you have the source for GADBannerView, examine it and see where the object reference is coming from.U should try to solve this error in that direction.

check ur admob version as well, becoz GDBBannerview is a part of Admob this might accour from that code.
or else try with other (older or newer version) of admob api.

Comment: can you please explain how can I do it? as I am just new to iOS developing I have no idea what to do.