# iPhone app Support 64Bit

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, undefined-symbol

I add `arm64` to my app:

```
Architecture
Valid Architecture
```

And when i build the application i get this error log:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DEFacebookComposeViewController.o
  "_kGADAdSizeBanner", referenced from:
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequestConnection", referenced from:
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libInMobi-4.5.1.a(IMCommonUtil+Private.o)
      objc-class-ref in VungleSDK(VungleSDK.o)
      objc-class-ref in MobFox(MobFox)
      objc-class-ref in iSoma(SOMAAdRequestBuilder.o)
      objc-class-ref in libAppLovinSdk.a(ALDataCollector.o)
      objc-class-ref in libAppLovinSdk.a(ALTaskFetchNextAd.o)
      objc-class-ref in libFlurryAds_6.0.0.a(libFlurryAds.a-arm64-master.o)
      ...
  "_CGSizeFromGADAdSize", referenced from:
      ...
  "_kGADAdSizeLeaderboard", referenced from:
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea what can be the problem?

Edit:

---

I update the `googleadmob` lib and `facebookSdk` but the other Framework already support the 64bit and i get this error msg:

```
d: warning: ignoring file /Users/App/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/App/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libInMobi-4.5.1.a(IMCommonUtil+Private.o)
      objc-class-ref in VungleSDK(VungleSDK.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADDevice.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureIdUtil.o)
      objc-class-ref in MobFox(MobFox)
      objc-class-ref in iSoma(SOMAAdRequestBuilder.o)
      objc-class-ref in libAppLovinSdk.a(ALDataCollector.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: The third-party libraries and frameworks that you are importing do not have arm64 support. Upgrade them.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Can you look at my edit

Comment: Just read the darned error message. AdSupport is the problem. - Also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12628989/341994

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messages are pretty clear. Those symbols are not defined for that architecture. You'll need a new build of every one of those libraries - a build that has a 64bit slice.

Comment: make sure it is using the right libs now, do you have both 32 and 64 in the project?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried holding the option key and doing Product -> Clean Build Folder? This would blow away any precompiled headers that were not aware of your arm64 compile target at the time they were generated. Try that and then build again.